# Sumar columnas de una matriz en Java y mostrarlo en pantalla

Tags: java, array, matrices, matriz

espero que se encuentren muy bien!

Estoy aprendiendo a crear matricez en java, necesito que el código sume todas la columnas y me las muestre en un solo resultado.

Estuve investigando y encontré un video, lo seguí y no me aparece ningún error al crearlo, sin embargo al correrlo las primeras partes todo sale bien, pero la suma no se muestra como debería ser.

Alguien me podría ayudar a encontrar el error? De verdad se los agradecería demasiado.

Este es el codigo

public static void main(String[] args) { //Inicio del Main

```
    int[][] matriz = new int[5][5]; //Pricinpal matriz

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) { //Crear la matriz
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        }
    } //Fin de crear la matriz

    String strMatriz = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) { //Llenar la matriz
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            strMatriz += "[" + matriz[i][j] + "]";
        } //Fin for j Str
        strMatriz += "\n";
    } //Fin de llenar la matriz

    int filas = matriz.length; //Tamaño de filas
    int columnas = matriz[0].length; // Tamaño de columnas

    int[][] resultado = new int[5][5]; //Suma de Columnas
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {// sumar todas las filas de esa columna       
            resultado[i][j] += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strMatriz);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero de filas es " + filas + " y de columnas es " + columnas);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La suma de las columnas es: " + resultado);
} //Fin del Main
```

}

Esta es la parte de la suma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al correrla muestra esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué el array resultado es una matriz de 5x5? Piensa un poco, si estás sumando columnas ¿No te basta un vector de 1x5? Por otro lado resultado es un vector, no es un string, por eso se muestra así. Checa [esta corrección](https://pastebin.com/nz6Er6W3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si vas a obtener los resultados de la suma de columnas tu matriz resultado debe ser de 1 columna y 5 filas,ya que solo vas a obtener 5 resultados.

```
int[][] resultado = new int[1][5]; //Suma de Columnas
    int sumaDeColumnas=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {// sumar todas las filas de esa columna  
           //ponemos 0 para que se acumulen las sumas solo en esa posición     
             resultado[0][j]+= matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
```

ahora solo vuelves a aplicar lo mismo que hiciste con strMtriz

```
 String matrizResultado="";
   for (int i=0;i<resultado.length;i++ ) {
       for (int j=0;j<resultado[i].length;j++ ) {
            matrizResultado += "[" + resultado[i][j] + "]";
       }
   }
```

para poder visualizarlo dentro de tu JoptionPane

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strMatriz);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero de filas es " + filas + " y de columnas es " + columnas);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La suma de las columnas es: " + matrizResultado);
```

Salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]